# XML Schema: Permit a tag only if another optional tag is provided

Tags: xml, xsd, schema-design

I'm trying to define an XML schema that has an optional tag, `sort_expression`. If that optional tag is provided, then a second optional tag, `alternate_sort_expression` is allowed, but it is conditional on the existence of the first tag.

For example, I want these examples to validate:

```xml
<indication>
    <label>A label for the item</label>
    <sort_expression>Some Value</sort_expression>
    <!-- one sort expression was provided -->
</indication>
```

or

```xml
<indication>
    <label>A label for the item</label>
    <!-- no sort expression was provided -->
</indication>
```

or

```xml
<indication>
    <label>A label for the item</label>
    <sort_expression>Some Value</sort_expression>
    <alternate_sort_expression>Some Value</alternate_sort_expression>
</indication>
```

but the following should not pass validation:

```xml
<indication>
    <label>A label for the item</label>
    <!-- no main sort expression was provided -->
    <alternate_sort_expression>INVALID</alternate_sort_expression>
</indication>
```

I thought the following schema, using a choice of two sequences would work. Unfortunately the schema itself is not validating; Altova XML Spy is telling me "the content model of complex type indication is ambiguous:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="indication">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="sort_expression" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="sort_expression" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="alternate_sort_expression" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an optional sequence that contains a mandatory `<sort_expression>` element and optional `<alternate_sort_expression>` elements.

Because they are in the same sequence, `<alternate_sort_expression>` appears only when `<sort_expression>` is present but also `<sort_expression>` can be omitted because the whole sequence can be omitted.

```
<xs:complexType name="indication">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="sort_expression" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="alternate_sort_expression" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible using nested sequences:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="sort_expression" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="alternate_sort_expression" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

... at least it validates your examples as desired.